# How do I restrict access of my S3 web site to specific domains or IP addresses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a static web site hosted in an S3 bucket. With an SSL certificate on AWS, let's say the site is `https://myawssite.com/somefolder/`. On some other page, say `http://containerpage.com`, I have an iframe in which I put

`<iframe src="https://myawssite.com/somefolder?url=/content/x83822" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

I want to allow the content to show only when the reference to `myawssite.com` is on `http://containerpage.com`, but I don't want to allow the viewing of the content if anyone just puts `https://myawssite.com/somefolder?url=/content/x8382` into a browser, or puts the iframe into their own web page (on a web site not at `myawssite.com`).

Assuming `containerpage.com` is at IP address 5.33.253.12, I thought I could do it with an s3 bucket policy like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "5.33.253.12/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is not working. Ideally I would like to specify the permitted domain (`containerpage.com`), instead of the IP address, but I can't even get the IP address to work.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong, or if the whole approach is not correct?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: What about using `aws:Referer` as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restricting access based upon Referer is not secure. It can be easily circumvented. A [simple web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=spoof+refer) reveals many methods to fake the `referer` field.

For a more secure method, see this StackOverflow answer: [My S3 Bucket Policy only applies to some Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61356250/174777)

Comment: Thanks! Reading the link you provided, I think the pre-signed URL sounds like the best approach. However, when you say "users should authenticate to your application", Assuming the "user" is any web page we want to authorize, how would the user get authorization without a formal login endpoint to retrieve the authorization token? This scenario doesn't seem so rare -- do you know of any examples I can find to understand it better?

Comment: Normally, private objects are private to specific users. For example, a photo-sharing website would only make photos available to the owner of a photo. It appears that you do not want to require users to login, but you still want to limit access to content to only "users of your application". In this situation, you can skip the authentication part, but still have your application generate pre-signed URLs. That way, if a search engine or scraping service used those URLs, they would not get access to any content. Only pages generated by your app would work correctly with "fresh" URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving the ip address which will refer to `http://containerpage.com/*`.

and as @marcin commented you should use `aws:refer`.

policy should be this like:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "http://containerpage.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

See [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4)

Comment: Thanks so much! I wanted to try this as an interim before going with what John Rotenstein mentioned. When I change the bucket policy, it seems that if I reload pages that worked before then they continue to work after the policy change -- I am thinking it has to do with the data being in the browser cache, perhaps. So if I visit containerpage.com, it works, then I look at the page source and copy out the myawssite.com and paste that into the browser (clearly not from containerpage.com), then it loads the content. That's why I'm thinking it has to do with the cache. Do you think that's correct?

Comment: It turns out that CloudFront by default strips headers like Referer, so that's why it was not working trying to restrict by header. In the CloudFront distribution, one can whitelist the Referer field and then S3 can filter the Get request by the Referer. Of course John pointed out Referers can be spoofed easily, but just in case others are having similar trouble!