# Storing files in amazon s3 and giving public URLs to users

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an image upload functionality on my website - I upload images directly to s3 bucket. What I do is I made that bucket public, I fetch images on my website and use public links of images from the s3 bucket to show them as html img tags.

Users of my website will take these images, possibly as links, and use them on their websites. I can see several problems here:

- links of images are direct links to aws
- the whole bucket is public
- there will be a lot of unpredictable reads

Its a better idea to use cdn here (probably cloudfront). How to integrate cdn into this process though?

Can I upload images directly into cdn, without storing them in s3? Why would I need s3 if I have a cdn?

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: S3 is storage, CDN is a front so generally you need to storage to have something that the CDN backs (or fronts).

Comment: If you have made the bucket public then, yes, anyone can access the objects. If you wish to control access, follow the advice on: [My S3 Bucket Policy only applies to some Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61356250/174777)

Comment: These objects should be viewable by anyone. I worry about the cost if people generate too many reads, and about the URL (what if I change the region of my aws account and all image urls will suddenly have a different domain?)

Answer (score 1):

S3 is still required, since Cloudfront uses S3 as its origin. S3 remains the data store, but Cloudfront caches these objects at the edge.

Check out this [walkthrough](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-cloudfront-walkthrough.html) on adding a Cloudfront distribution to cache your static files.

This will allow you to use your own url for the static content, as well as restrict direct access to S3 via [Origin Access Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, cloudfront needs an 'origin' and often types that origin is S3, so you can't use just cloudfront - the images need to exist somewhere.

One precaution you could do (not clear from your question if you are - you said the links are 'directy to aws'),  is to serve all of these images under your own domain name - either directly from s3, or with cloudfront - doing that now will ensure that if you do ever need to switch where you store the images, you customers won't need to change their links and the process would be seamless for them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats a very good and helpful point. So I should make a rest endpoint accepting filename as parameter, and return content from s3 as a response, and use that endpoint as absolute image link later on? Is it a good practice? My server will serve as a proxy to images in this case.

Comment: I would use an absolute link, as long as it is served directly from your own domain, I see no downside. An api rest endpoint adds unneeded complexity imo.